# Unable to extract information using NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an iPhone application which will use NSRegularExpression to match pattern from a string to extract information. Here I am trying to extract the mailTo link from an email header. I have successfully retrieved the email header string and now I am applying the the search pattern using  NSregularExpression to get the email id from the header string.

This is the header text from where I want to extract mailTo :

> List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:suksh-1142-5451-d8135921c2e2d40400ab02fa31eda529@usub.mailserv.in>?subject=Unsubscribe>,<http://suksh.mailserv.in/suksh/?p=unsubscribe&mid=5451&uid=d8135921c2e2d40400ab02fa31eda529>>

This is the search pattern:

```
mailto:(?<address>[^\?^>]+)\??(?<params>[^>]+)?
```

my code is like this

```
NSString *str= @"List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:suksh-1142-5451-d8135921c2e2d40400ab02fa31eda529@usub.mailserv.in>?subject=Unsubscribe>,<http://suksh.mailserv.in/suksh/?p=unsubscribe&mid=5451&uid=d8135921c2e2d40400ab02fa31eda529>>";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"mailto:(?<address>[^\?^>]+)\??(?<params>[^>]+)?"];
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [str substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
    NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@",substringForFirstMatch);
}
```

but when I am going to create the NSRegularExpression object by the help of `regularExpressionWithPattern:` it is returning nil object.

Please assist me what can be the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this is the only issue, but you haven't escaped the backslashes in your regex.

Comment: Also, there is no `regularExpressionWithPattern:` method, it's called `regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:` and the `error` parameter should give you an idea what's wrong with your expression.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern string will be processed twice: once by the compiler, then by `NSRegularExpression`. You must escape backslashes to ensure the compiler doesn't process each "\?".

Neither the [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) nor [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) documentation mentions support for named capture groups (`(?<name>pattern)`); that could cause the parsing of the pattern to fail or the match to fail.

Use [`regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRegularExpression/regularExpressionWithPattern%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) when you create the regular expression so you can get an [error](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH201-SW1) object, which will tell you why construction failed.

```
NSError *theError;
// '?\?(' is to prevent '??(' from being interpreted as a trigraph
NSString *pattern = @"mailto:(?<address>[^\\?^>]+)\\?\?(?<params>[^>]+)?";
NSRegularExpression *regex;
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch;

regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern 
            options:0 error:&theError];
if (regex) {
    rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:str 
                            options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

    if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
        NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [str substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
        NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@",substringForFirstMatch);
    }
} else {
    // couldn't compile RE
    NSAlert *errorAlert;
    if (theError) {
        errorAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:theError];
    } else {
        NSString *errorMsg = @"Couldn't parse unsubscribe header because the pattern /%@/ isn't a valid regular expression.";
        errorAlert = [NSAlert 
                 alertWithMessageText:@"Invalid Pattern"
                        defaultButton:nil
                      alternateButton:nil
                          otherButton:nil
            informativeTextWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:errorMsg, pattern]];
    }
    [theAlert runModal]; // Ignore return value.
}
```