# Captured group regex NSRegularExpression iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to execute the following regex: `^(\$.)([\d]{1,10})?`

The result for the `$C14325` string at https://regex101.com is `[0-2]:"$C"` and `[2-7]:"14325"`.

But, when I the following code is executed using `NSRegularExpression`, then it returns as single matching item, rather than a group.

Basically, I am trying to group those results and finding a way what result corresponds to which regex.

```
NSString *regexStr=@"^(\\$.)([\\d]{1,10})?";
NSString *inputStr=@"$C14325";
NSError *regexError;
NSRegularExpression *aRegx=[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];
NSArray *results=[aRegx matchesInString:inputStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, inputStr.length)];
```

There was answer at [Named capture groups with NSRegularExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814974/named-capture-groups-with-nsregularexpression) , but I think `rangeAtIndex` will throw exception if its not able to find the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the regex part right. All you need to do is iterating matches inside the `results`:

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in results) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSRange first = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSRange second = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"1:%@ 2:%@.", [NSValue valueWithRange:first], [NSValue valueWithRange:second]);
}
```

> `1:NSRange: {0, 2} 2:NSRange: {2, 5}.`

Comment: I thought printing results would print that content, group wise.