# Named capture groups in NSRegularExpression - get a range's group's name

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression, icu

Apple says that NSRegularExpression is based on the ICU Regular Expression library: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/

> The pattern syntax currently supported is that specified by ICU. The ICU regular expressions are described at http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp.

That page (on icu-project.org) claims that Named Capture Groups are now supported, using the same syntax as .NET Regular Expressions:

> `(?<name>...)`    Named capture group. The `<angle brackets>` are literal - they appear in the pattern.

I have written a program which gets a single match with multiple ranges which seem correct - though each range is returned twice (for reasons unknown) - but the only information I have is the range's index and its text range.

For example, the regex: `^(?<foo>foo)\.(?<bar>bar)\.(?<bar2>baz)$` with test string `foo.bar.baz`

Gives me these results:

```
Idx    Start    Length     Text
0      0        11         foo.bar.baz
1      0         3         foo
2      4         3         bar
3      8         3         baz
```

Is there any way to know that "`baz`" came from the capture-group `bar2`?

Comment: Did you looked at [Named capture groups with NSRegularExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814974/named-capture-groups-with-nsregularexpression)?

Comment: @Thomas I did see that, however it is from 2014 and the discussions all say that Named Capture Groups are not supported - however (at least on iOS 9 and OS X 10.11) the do appear to be supported - and they're working on my machines at least, I just can't map from a result range back to the group they came from.

Comment: And the Apple doc state that is *Available in iOS 4.0 and later*...

Comment: @Thomas The documentation states that the `NSRegularExpression` class was added to iOS 4.0, not that support for Named Capture Groups was added in iOS 4.0.

Comment: @Thomas In fact, Apple's own documentation for `NSRegularExpression` does not list the syntax for Named Capture Groups, it only appears on ICU's own documentation, suggesting that Named Capture Groups are a recent addition.

Answer (score 11):

Since iOS11 named capture groups are supported. `NSTextCheckingResult` has the function [`open func range(withName name: String) -> NSRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstextcheckingresult/2915200-range).

Using the regex: `^(?<foo>foo)\.(?<bar>bar)\.(?<bar2>baz)$` with the test string `foo.bar.baz` gives 4 result matches. The function `match.range(withName: "bar2")` returns the range for the String `baz`

Comment: I wrote an extension based on that to create a dictionary out of all named capture groups and their values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48309290/235297

Answer (score 3):

I have worked on the example as created by [Daniele Bernardini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2028375/daniele-bernardini).

There are a number of changes:

- First of all the code is now compatible with Swift 3
- The code of Daniele has a defect that it will not capture nested captures. I have made the regular expressions slightly less aggressive to allow for nesting of capture groups.
- I prefer to actually receive the actual captures in a Set. I added a method named `captureGroups()` that returns the captures as a string instead of a range.

  ```
  import Foundation

  extension String {
      func matchingStrings(regex: String) -> [[String]] {
          guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: []) else { return [] }
          let nsString = self as NSString
          let results  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
          return results.map { result in
              (0..<result.numberOfRanges).map { result.rangeAt($0).location != NSNotFound
                  ? nsString.substring(with: result.rangeAt($0))
                  : ""
              }
          }
      }

      func range(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
          guard
              let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
              let to16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location + nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
              let from = from16.samePosition(in: self),
              let to = to16.samePosition(in: self)
              else { return nil }
          return from ..< to
      }

  }

  extension NSRegularExpression {
      typealias GroupNamesSearchResult = (NSTextCheckingResult, NSTextCheckingResult, Int)

      private func textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups() -> [String:GroupNamesSearchResult] {
          var groupnames = [String:GroupNamesSearchResult]()

          guard let greg = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\(\\?<([\\w\\a_-]*)>$", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.dotMatchesLineSeparators) else {
              // This never happens but the alternative is to make this method throwing
              return groupnames
          }
          guard let reg = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\(.*?>", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.dotMatchesLineSeparators) else {
              // This never happens but the alternative is to make this method throwing
              return groupnames
          }
          let m = reg.matches(in: self.pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.withTransparentBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.pattern.utf16.count))
          for (n,g) in m.enumerated() {
              let r = self.pattern.range(from: g.rangeAt(0))
              let gstring = self.pattern.substring(with: r!)
              let gmatch = greg.matches(in: gstring, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.anchored, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: gstring.utf16.count))
              if gmatch.count > 0{
                  let r2 = gstring.range(from: gmatch[0].rangeAt(1))!
                  groupnames[gstring.substring(with: r2)] = (g, gmatch[0],n)
              }

          }
          return groupnames
      }

      func indexOfNamedCaptureGroups() throws -> [String:Int] {
          var groupnames = [String:Int]()
          for (name,(_,_,n)) in try self.textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups() {
              groupnames[name] = n + 1
          }
          return groupnames
      }

      func rangesOfNamedCaptureGroups(match:NSTextCheckingResult) throws -> [String:Range<Int>] {
          var ranges = [String:Range<Int>]()
          for (name,(_,_,n)) in try self.textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups() {
              ranges[name] = match.rangeAt(n+1).toRange()
          }
          return ranges
      }

      private func nameForIndex(_ index: Int, from: [String:GroupNamesSearchResult]) -> String? {
          for (name,(_,_,n)) in from {
              if (n + 1) == index {
                  return name
              }
          }
          return nil
      }

      func captureGroups(string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = []) -> [String:String] {
          return captureGroups(string: string, options: options, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
      }

      func captureGroups(string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: NSRange) -> [String:String] {
          var dict = [String:String]()
          let matchResult = matches(in: string, options: options, range: range)
          let names = try self.textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups()
          for (n,m) in matchResult.enumerated() {
              for i in (0..<m.numberOfRanges) {
                  let r2 = string.range(from: m.rangeAt(i))!
                  let g = string.substring(with: r2)
                  if let name = nameForIndex(i, from: names) {
                      dict[name] = g
                  }
              }
          }
          return dict
      }
  }
  ```

An example of using the new method `captureGroups()` is:

```
    let node = "'test_literal'"
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?<all>(?<delimiter>'|\")(?<value>.*)(?:\\k<delimiter>))$", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.dotMatchesLineSeparators)
    let match2 = regex.captureGroups(string: node, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.anchored)
    print(match2)
```

And it will print:

["delimiter": "\'", "all": "\'test_literal\'", "value": "test_literal"]

Comment: Thank you, you saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and ended up backing my own solution. Feel free to comment or improve ;-)

```
extension NSRegularExpression {
    typealias GroupNamesSearchResult = (NSTextCheckingResult, NSTextCheckingResult, Int)

    private func textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups() throws -> [String:GroupNamesSearchResult] {
        var groupnames = [String:GroupNamesSearchResult]()

        let greg = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\(\\?<([\\w\\a_-]*)>.*\\)$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators)
        let reg = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\([^\\(\\)]*\\)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators)
        let m = reg.matchesInString(self.pattern, options: NSMatchingOptions.WithTransparentBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.pattern.utf16.count))
        for (n,g) in m.enumerate() {
            let gstring = self.pattern.substringWithRange(g.rangeAtIndex(0).toRange()!)
            print(self.pattern.substringWithRange(g.rangeAtIndex(0).toRange()!))
            let gmatch = greg.matchesInString(gstring, options: NSMatchingOptions.Anchored, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: gstring.utf16.count))
            if gmatch.count > 0{
                groupnames[gstring.substringWithRange(gmatch[0].rangeAtIndex(1).toRange()!)] = (g,gmatch[0],n)
            }

        }
        return groupnames
    }
    func indexOfNamedCaptureGroups() throws -> [String:Int] {
        var groupnames = [String:Int]()
        for (name,(_,_,n)) in try self.textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups() {
            groupnames[name] = n + 1
        }
        //print(groupnames)
        return groupnames
    }

    func rangesOfNamedCaptureGroups(match:NSTextCheckingResult) throws -> [String:Range<Int>] {
        var ranges = [String:Range<Int>]()
        for (name,(_,_,n)) in try self.textCheckingResultsOfNamedCaptureGroups() {
            ranges[name] = match.rangeAtIndex(n+1).toRange()
        }
        return ranges
    }
}
```

Here is an usage example:

```
let node = "'test_literal'"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?<delimiter>'|\")(?<value>.*)(?:\\k<delimiter>)$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators)
let match = regex.matchesInString(node, options: NSMatchingOptions.Anchored, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: node.utf16.count))
if match.count > 0 {

    let ranges = try regex.rangesOfNamedCaptureGroups(match[0])
    guard let range = ranges["value"] else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Can you please amend your answer with some usage examples?

Comment: done. After taking a second look I also realised it was not obvious... Wrote this code a few months ago and there were reasons to go to have matches and ranges on 2 separate calls.